# Is there a way to edit Leaflet shapes with Leaflet.Draw without clicking on 'Edit Shape' on draw controller?

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet, leaflet.draw

Leaflet has a plugin called Leaflet.Draw that allows users to edit shapes in a FeatureGroup.

In the draw controller, there is a button that the users can click to edit drawn shapes. The users can then modify the geometry and click 'Save' to save the changes.

However, as part of the UI features, I want to enable Leaflet.draw's edit features when the users double click on the shape.

If I can detect a double click event with Leaflet, how should I fire the Edit Layer event without touching the draw controller at all? I read the docs for Leaflet.draw and could not find the relevant event handler.

Comment: I have built a drawing/editing plugin for leaflet, leaflet-geoman, that allows you to enable editing/drawing through an API as well. So you could enable drawing/edit mode inside the dblclick event handler.
 https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman